# Page Cycles - Right way to input data to database

Tags: asp.net, database, linq, prerender

I have a page that has a few textboxes and a dropdownlist.
When a logged in user opens this page the boxes are filled with data that he has input before, he can change the data and update it by pushing a update button.
There is also that dropdownlist which has a dynamically populated data for him to choose from.

What is the best way to make this page work. Where in the page cycles do I populate the forms and where do I input the data to the datatable.

At the moment I'm populating the data on PreRender but the dropdownlist on the preinit. I have a button event handler to do the update on the datatable. The problem is that the autopostback messes up the data in the dropdownlist because its dynamically populated, how would I go by fixing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I follow in most of my cases

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        InitDropdDownListes();
        LoadDataFromDataBase();
    }

}

void InitDropdDownListes()
{
    // fill drop down boxes

}

void LoadDataFromDataBase()
{
    // load from database

}

protected void OnDropdownListChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // reload the new data from database
    LoadDataFromDataBase();
}


protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Save to database

}
```

Comment: Oh, the memories...  Fifteen hundred methods that all start with `if(!IsPostBack)`.

Comment: @Will - and as soon as I read this question it all came flooding back. One man's memories is another man's nightmare (ie. the person having to maintain the old ASP.NET codebase :)

Comment: but here you populate the dropdownlist only if its not a postback, when i push the save button it posts back and then there are no items in the dropdownlists. dynamatically populated data doesnt stay there after postback..

Comment: @eski I will check it, but I think that they saved on viewstate - do you have enable the viewstate for the DropDownListBox ? Maybe you need to populate by hand on function, I will check out to see what I do.

Comment: @Aristos yes the viewstate is enabled. I'm populating the dropdownlist by doing linq query and binding it to the datasource on it. Maybe i need to add each item with a foreach loop to the list ?

Comment: Ahhhh.. *feelingstupid* I'm using masterpages and the viewstate on the content placeholder was false. The input boxes and dropdownlist were in that placeholder. ;)